# Jess missing from episodes of New Girl, Season 5

Tags: new-girl

Zooey Deschanel's Jess, the titular "New Girl", is absent from several episodes of season 5.

In-story she has been called for jury duty and remains sequestered. As the main character, is there a real-world explanation?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[From Bustle](http://www.bustle.com/articles/142380-why-did-zooey-deschanel-leave-new-girl-the-actress-had-a-very-good-reason):

> So why exactly did Zooey Deschanel leave New Girl in the first place
>   and completely abandon her Season 5 duties? She pretty much has the
>   best excuse in the world: ***she was off enjoying the labors of
>   motherhood — quite literally.***
>
> Yes, unless you've been living under a rock for the last year, you
>   know that the actress, who announced her pregnancy in early 2015, gave
>   birth to a healthy baby girl in July and has therefore been on
>   maternity leave for the past several months.

If it makes you feel any better, I've clearly been "living under a rock" too.

Comment: How could you not start this answer with "To take care of *her* New Girl" :-p

Comment: It truly was a missed opportunity. I'm disappointed with myself now.